# Regex: Matching,parsing an FTP response to a request

Tags: regex, parsing, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Here's what i'm trying to do:

I what to have some FTP functionality in one of my apps (this is just for myself, not a business application or such) and since I didn't wanted to write all that FTP request/response  code for myself, I (being the lazy man I am) search the internet for an FTP wrapper.
I have found [this DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11991/An-FTP-client-library-for-NET-2-0).

This is all very great, works like a charm. Except for one thing: when I request the LastWriteTime of a specific file ON the FTP server, the DLL is giving me strange dates (namely, prints out fictional dates). I've been able to find the problem. Whenever you send a request to the FTP server, it sends back a one line response, which has a very special format. Now what i've been able to gather, this format is different for most of the servers, my wrapper DLL comes with 6 pre-defined response formats, but my FTP server sends back a 7th one. Here's a response to a request and the REGEX formats:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 user   user          594 Jun 11 03:44 random_log.file
```

here are my regex parsing formats:

```
 "(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{4})\s+(?<name>.+)", _
 "(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{4})\s+(?<name>.+)", _
 "(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+(?<name>.+)", _
 "(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+(?<name>.+)", _
 "(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})(\s+)(?<size>(\d+))(\s+)(?<ctbit>(\w+\s\w+))(\s+)(?<size2>(\d+))\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<name>.+)", _
 "(?<timestamp>\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}[Aa|Pp][mM])\s+(?<dir>\<\w+\>){0,1}(?<size>\d+){0,1}\s+(?<name>.+)"
```

Non of these seem to be able to parse the datetime correctly and since I have no idea how to do that, can a REGEX pro please write me a ParsingFormat that would be able to parse the above FTP response?

Comment: Is that request tab-delimited? It seems odd that you're using regex for this, at least without first splitting on tabs or something. The request is in a very regular format; you could probably do a lot of the heavy lifting with plain old string functions.

Comment: @Justin Yeah well, here's what the problem was: you see the date the server returns? Jun 11 03:44 , after I'm parsing the responses: 
_fileDateTime = Date.Parse(m.Groups("timestamp").Value)  this messes up, why? because Date.Parse() cannot parse this kind of date format, seems strange that the FTP doesn't returns the year, but whatever

Comment: @Justin a custom date formatter should do the trick at this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both a hand-check and `irb` check of the fourth format shows that it *does* match:

```
> re=/(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+(?<name>.+)/
=> /(?<dir>[\-d])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+(?<name>.+)/
> m=re.match("-rw-r--r--    1 user   user          594 Jun 11 03:44 random_log.file")
=> #<MatchData "-rw-r--r--    1 user   user          594 Jun 11 03:44 random_log.file" dir:"-" permission:"rw-r--r--" size:"594" timestamp:"Jun 11 03:44" name:"random_log.file">
> m['dir']
=> "-"
> m['permission']
=> "rw-r--r--"
> m['size']
=> "594"
> m['timestamp']
=> "Jun 11 03:44"
> m['name']
=> "random_log.file"
>
```

I think the pile of regular expressions are fine. Perhaps you need to look elsewhere for the problem.